# How to write Query in JPA Repository for the following hibernate code snipet?

Tags: java

```java
public List<LoginDetails> getLoginDetails(String userId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    // LoginDetails loginDetails = null;

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(LoginDetails.class)
                .addOrder(Order.desc("login_date"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("user_id", userId))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("live_ind", true));

    criteria.setMaxResults(2);

    List<LoginDetails> details = criteria.list();


    return details;
}
```

I am trying to use the above method in jpa repository. How do I write a query for the above code snippet?

Comment: Are you getting some error? Or do you need do this in specific lib?

Comment: yes i am changing a small project  to jpa repository which was previously done in hibernate using dao. and i am confused how to put native query for this